# networking - Ubuntu 18.04 VPN Connection

Tags: sudo, laptop

I'm new in the Linux world. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and want to connect from a VPN to our server at the University. I keep on searching but I cann't find the command for it.

Could someone pls help??
thank

Answer (score 0):

Open the gnome Control Center and find the Network section. You will find here the VPN section. You may need some technical information about the VPN you want to connect to.

Open the gnome control center from a terminal or [Alt]+[F2]:

`gnome-control-center -s network`

[Ubuntu Help: Connect to a VPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-vpn-connect.html)

[Ubuntu Help: VpnClient](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient)